# Mapping dynamic odata routes with ASP.NET Core OData 8.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, odata

I've got an application where the EDM datatypes are generated during the runtime of the application (they can even change during runtime). Based loosely on [OData DynamicEDMModelCreation Sample](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApiCore/DynamicEdmModelCreation) - refactored to use the new endpoint routing. There the EDM model is dynamically generated at runtime and all requests are forwarded to the same controller.

Now I wanted to update to the newest [ASP.NET Core OData 8.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/) and the whole routing changed so that the current workaround does not work anymore.

I've read the two blog posts of the update [Blog1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/asp-net-odata-8-0-preview-for-net-5/)[Blog2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/routing-in-asp-net-core-8-0-preview/) and it seems that I can't use the "old" workaround anymore as the function *MapODataRoute()* within the endpoints is now gone. It also seems that none of the built-in routing convention work for my use-case as all require the EDM model to be present at debug time.

Maybe I can use a custom *IODataControllerActionConvention*. I tried to active the convention by adding it to the Routing Convention but it seems I'm still missing a piece how to activate it.

```
services.TryAddEnumerable(
    ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IODataControllerActionConvention, MyEntitySetRoutingConvention>());
```

Does this approach even work? Is it even possible to activate a dynamic model in the new odata preview? or does anybody has a slight idea how to approach a dynamic routing for the new odata 8.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example for dynamic routing and dynamic model here:

https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/master/sample/ODataDynamicModel/
See `MyODataRoutingApplicationModelProvider` and `MyODataRoutingMatcherPolicy` which will pass a custom IEdmModel to the controller.

The `HandleAllController` can handle different types and edm models in a dynamic way.

Comment: well if I just have seen that solution earlier. I like my solution more as it uses only that parts which are needed of OData (De-Serialization/Validation) instead of juggle around with routes so I will stick with mine. But I will mark your solution as answer as it the more or less official and it uses the same approach which was asked in my question - so thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

So after 5 days of internal OData debugging I managed to get it to work. Here are the necessary steps:

First remove all OData calls/attributes from your controller/configure services which might do funky stuff (`ODataRoutingAttribute` or `AddOData()`)

Create a simple asp.net controller with the route to your liking and map it in the endpoints

```
[ApiController]
[Route("odata/v{version}/{Path?}")]
public class HandleAllController : ControllerBase { ... }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  ...
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
  }
}
```

Create and register your InputFormatWrapper and OutputFormatWrapper

```
public class ConfigureMvcOptionsFormatters : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions> 
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
    public ConfigureMvcOptionsFormatters(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _services = services;
    } 

    public void Configure(MvcOptions options)
    { 
        options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new ODataInputFormatWrapper(_services));
        options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new OdataOutputFormatWrapper(_services));
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureMvcOptionsFormatters>();
    ...
}

public class ODataInputFormatWrapper : InputFormatter
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ODataInputFormatter _oDataInputFormatter;

    public ODataInputFormatWrapper(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        //JSON and default is first - see factory comments 
        _oDataInputFormatter = ODataInputFormatterFactory.Create().First();
    }
    
    public override bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        if (!ODataWrapperHelper.IsRequestValid(context.HttpContext, _serviceProvider))
            return false;

        return _oDataInputFormatter.CanRead(context);
    }

    public override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        return _oDataInputFormatter!.ReadRequestBodyAsync(context);
    }
}

// The OutputFormatWrapper looks like the InputFormatWrapper
```

Within the `ODataWrapperHelper` you can check stuff and get/set your dynamic edmModel. It is necessary in the end to set these `ODataFeature()`... That's not beautiful but it gets the dynamic job done...

```
public static bool IsRequestValid(HttpContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
  //... Do stuff, get datasource
  var edmModel = dataSource!.GetModel();
  var oSegment = new EntitySetSegment(new EdmEntitySet(edmModel.EntityContainer, targetEntity, edmModel.SchemaElements.First(x => targetEntity == x.Name) as EdmEntityType));
   context.ODataFeature().Services = serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider;
   context.ODataFeature().Model = edmModel;
   context.ODataFeature().Path = new ODataPath(oSegment);

   return true;
 }
```

Now to the ugly stuff: We still need to register some ODataService in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`. I added a function there called `AddCustomODataService(services)` and there you can either register ~40 services yourself or do some funky reflection...

So maybe if someone from the odata team reads this, please consider opening `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Abstracts.ContainerBuilderExtensions`

I created a
`public class CustomODataServiceContainerBuilder : IContainerBuilder` which is a copy of the internal `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Abstracts.DefaultContainerBuilder` there I added the function:

```
public void AddServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  foreach (var service in Services)
  {
    services.Add(service);
   }
}
```

and the ugly `AddCustomODataServices(IServiceCollection services)`

```
private void AddCustomODataService(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var builder = new CustomODataServiceContainerBuilder();
    builder.AddDefaultODataServices();

    //AddDefaultWebApiServices in ContainerBuilderExtensions is internal...
    var addDefaultWebApiServices = typeof(ODataFeature).Assembly.GetTypes()
            .First(x => x.FullName == "Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Abstracts.ContainerBuilderExtensions")
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public)
            .First(x => x.Name == "AddDefaultWebApiServices");

    addDefaultWebApiServices.Invoke(null, new object?[]{builder});
    builder.AddServices(services);
}
```

Now the controller should work again (with odataQueryContext and serialization in place) - Example:

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<IActionResult> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   //... get model and entitytype
   var queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(model, entityType, null);
   var queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, Request);

   return (Collection<IEdmEntityObject>)myCollection;
}

[HttpPost]
public Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] IEdmEntityObject entityDataObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //Do something with IEdmEntityObject
    return Ok()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new MapODataRoute has been moved as options inside of the .AddOData() method. Here is an Example:

````
ODataModelBuilder odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
odataBuilder.EntitySet<Example>("Example");
var odataModel = odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(config => {
    config.AddRouteComponents(odataModel);
});```
````